# Is there any way to set ccze color scheme?

Tags: colorscheme, filetype

I want to use [ccze](https://github.com/cornet/ccze) color scheme for log file specific.

```
augroup LogColorscheme
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType log colorscheme ccze
augroup END
```

However, this installed color scheme on system-wide

```
sudo pacman -Q ccze                                                                                                                                                  
ccze 0.2.1-12
```

is not valid for Vim.

How can I handle it or is there any alternative color scheme similar to ccze?

Comment: You can't use [ccze](https://github.com/cornet/ccze) with Vim, as it uses its own internal mechanism for parsing text and applying visual attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a confusion between `syntax` and `colorscheme`.

With a `syntax` Vim associates to some characters or words a highlighting group that is colorized according to the `colorscheme`

By default log files has not file type and no syntax (all the characters are considered equivalent).

The [vim-log-highligthing](https://github.com/MTDL9/vim-log-highlighting) plugin introduces a logging syntax inspired by `ccze`

The colors or your `colorscheme` are then applied to the introduced logging syntax.

Here is how it looks with the [Nord](https://github.com/nordtheme/vim) colorization

[image]